# How to configure React Routes for different domains pointing to the same application with different URLs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

We have a working React app for `http://domain1.com/directory/members/jim`

We'd like to use the same app for `http://domain2.com/jim`

How can we define the routes for the two domains?  Or can we put in place a substitution algorithm somewhere?

Comment: you can use window.location to view the incoming requested url.

Answer (score 1):

You can make both urls work for all domains, but then you can't have a member named "directory". That is a really ugly restriction.

Why don't you just serve 2 different apps on the 2 domains? They can still share 99 % of the code.

Comment: Isn't there something that can be done at the server level to display the URL but transpose it via substitution to the full URL used by the app?

Comment: @teleman No. The URL is the URL. There is nothing the server can do to hide it.